# C# using CoreAudioApi it wont mute and unmute at a specific time

Tags: c#, audio

I am using CoreAudioApi and i have a problem i want in a specified time of day to Mute/Unmute my PC volume. when i put the mute/unmute on a button its ok... but i want to press the button to start the timer and the api should automaticaly work at the specified time.

this is just a test code and i cant make it work it runes but it wont mute/unute but the (":") is "flashing" as it should...

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    MMDevice defaultDevice = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);

    hr = DateTime.UtcNow.Hour;
    min = DateTime.UtcNow.Minute;
    sec = DateTime.UtcNow.Second;

    if (hr > 12)
        hr -= 12;

    if (sec % 2 == 0)
    {
        lblTime.Text = hr+1 + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    }
    else
    {
        lblTime.Text = hr+1 + " " + min + " " + sec;
    }

    if (hr == 13 && min == 37 && sec == 0)
    {
        defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
    }
    else if (hr == 13 && min == 37 && sec == 5)
    {
        defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = false;
    }
    else if (hr == 13 && min == 37 && sec == 10)
    {
        defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title  is probably totally misleading.

Comment: What is your timer interval?

Comment: Set it more frequently, for example to 350.  Also, see if mute/unmute works on a button click.

Comment: Yes it does work on button click and i tried but its the same

Comment: its a project for a school they want to play music during the brakes and mute it during class

so i need the code to get my system time and then when for example its 9am the music will mute and at 9:45am it will start again

Comment: have you tried cscore? tested endpointvolume api several times on different machines with different devices and it worked. http://cscore.codeplex.com/